# DjangoFilterBackend not working with my models (manytomany)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a Django REST project in which I used the DjangoFilterBackend from django-rest-framework-filters[github link](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters).

This backend works well for some of my models which has ForeignKey & ManyToMany relations, however, it just doesn't work for some other models and always gives me an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'verbose_name'`.
my model:

```
from django.db import models
from authuser.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from corporation.models import Corporation


class Organization(AbstractUser):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Corporation, verbose_name='company',
                            related_name='organizations',
                            null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='contact_name', default='')
    contact_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, verbose_name='contact_phone')
    contact_email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,     verbose_name='contact_email', default='')
    about_us = models.TextField(null=True, verbose_name='about_us')
    info_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False,     verbose_name='info_completed')

    objects = BaseUserManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date_joined',)
```

my views:

```
class OrganizationDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrganizationSerializer
    queryset = Organization.objects.all()



class OrganizationListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Organization.objects.all()
    permission_classes = ()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == "POST":
            return CreateOrganizationSerializer
        return OrganizationSerializer

    filter_backends = (
        rest_backends.DjangoFilterBackend,
        filters.SearchFilter,
        filters.OrderingFilter,
    )
    filter_fields = (
        'contact_name',
    )
    filter_class = OrganizationFilter
    search_fields = (
        # 'company',
                     'contact_name',
                     'contact_email', 'contact_phone',
                     'description',
    )
    ordering = ('date_joined')
```

my filterset:

```
class OrganizationFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    company = filters.RelatedFilter(CorporationFilter, name='company')
    description = filters.AllLookupsFilter(name='description')
    contact_name = filters.AllLookupsFilter(name='contact_name')
    contact_phone = filters.AllLookupsFilter(name='contact_phone')
    contact_email = filters.AllLookupsFilter(name='contact_email')

    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = (
            'company',
            'description', 'contact_name', 'contact_phone',
            'contact_email',
        )
```

my serializer:

```
class OrganizationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Corporation.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = ('id', 'company',
                  'contact_name', 'contact_email',
                  'contact_phone', 'info_completed')
```

The CRUD operations are fine. It just gives me the attribute error when listing organizations:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
E.........
======================================================================
ERROR: test_list_organizations (organization.tests.SimpleTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\landi-django\organization\tests.py", line 73, in test_list_organizati
ons
    response = client.get('/organizations?contact_name=Tingtao')
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 160,
 in get
    response = super(APIClient, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 86,
in get
    return self.generic('GET', path, **r)
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\compat.py", line 18
9, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 157,
 in request
    return super(APIClient, self).request(**kwargs)
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 109,
 in request
    request = super(APIRequestFactory, self).request(**kwargs)
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 440,
in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", lin
e 111, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py",
line 57, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", lin
e 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 407
, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 404
, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line
311, in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 40
, in list
    instance = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line
144, in filter_queryset
    queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_filters\backends.py
", line 45, in filter_queryset
    _filter = filter_class(request.QUERY_PARAMS, queryset=queryset)
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_filters\filterset.p
y", line 61, in __init__
    f = self.filter_for_field(field, filter_.name)
  File "F:\landi-django\env\lib\site-packages\django_filters\filterset.py", line
 400, in filter_for_field
    'label': capfirst(f.verbose_name),
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'verbose_name'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also tried commenting line 400 in django_filters\filterset.py, but it gives me more errors. 
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: The issue is most likely related to the `description` field on your `FilterSet` which doesn't appear to be a field on the `Organization` model. Maybe it should have been `about_us`? (If this is the case, I can write up a more detailed answer)

Comment: Hi Kevin, Yes you're right. I changed the field to `about_us`  and it's now all working well. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On your `OrganizationFilter`, you are defining a `description` field that can be used to filter down to `Organization` objects. The `description` field does not exist on the `Organization` model though, so django-filter is not able to filter the queryset based on that field. You do appear to have an `about_us` field, which I'm guessing is what you meant to use.

You can fix this issue by either renaming the field on the `OrganizationFilter` to `about_us`, or setting the `name` on the `description` field to be `about_us`, so django-filter uses that field instead.

```
class OrganizationFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    company = filters.RelatedFilter(CorporationFilter, name='company')
    about_us = filters.AllLookupsFilter(name='about_us')
    contact_name = filters.AllLookupsFilter(name='contact_name')
    contact_phone = filters.AllLookupsFilter(name='contact_phone')
    contact_email = filters.AllLookupsFilter(name='contact_email')

    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = (
            'company',
            'description', 'contact_name', 'contact_phone',
            'contact_email',
        )
```

Either of these changes should make it work without throwing an error.